# How to set query for cron jobs in windows task schedular with php and xampp?

Tags: php, cron, xampp, scheduled-tasks

Basically i want if any user will registered himself in system. After 1 month of creation date user should be delete from db automatically.
In my table i have `creationDate` column.  I am done with my creating scheduler for system. its working. I just want to know what query will be set for my kind of thing.
Below is my code for cron.php:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$sql  = mysqli_query($conn,'select  *  from user where createdDate<=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY');
$data = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($data > 0)
{   
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
        {           
            $id = $row['userId'];
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM user where userId='".$id."'");
        }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Follow below method to hit your file/function using **powershell**

Open Windows Task schedular

- Create Basic Task wizard
- Set Tigger Option according to your requirement
- Set Action to "Start a program"
- Set Program/script = **powershell**
- Add arguments command = **PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://domainName/functionName -Method GET**
- Finalize it and then edit trigger with advance setting to set every minutes indefinitely